# Probability we have to draw x times (without replacement) before we get what we want

Tags: probability, random-variables

There was an example "fun" problem during one of my lectures that I am a bit confused about (prof went too fast).

The problem is:
Suppose we have cards in a bag. The cards are of 2 types. There are m monster cards and n spell cards. Suppose we pick a random card from the bag without replacement (one at a time) each uniformly at random until we get a spell card. If X is the number of cards we have to pick, what is P(X=k) if $k \in \{1,...,m\}$

The way it was done is that each monster card was marked with a number 1,...,m and we created Bernoulli Random Vars $X_i$ for each marked monster card. So $X_i=1$ means we pick monster card marked i before any spell card is picked. and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then they said that $P(X_i=1) = 1/(1+n)$. This part I don't get. How did they get this? I get $X=X_1 +...X_m $ but using this fact how would you find what $P(X=k)$ is?

Comment: (1) $P(X_i = 1) = 1/(1+n)$ because if you consider the $n+1$ cards consisting of the specific monster card and the $n$ spell cards, then $X_i = 1$ iff the monster card comes first among these $n+1$ cards.  (2) However, there is no easy way (that I can see) going from this to $P(X= k)$.  You can easily get $E[X]$ by linearity of expectation, but I dont see a good way to get the actual distribution $P(X=k)$ by using $P(X_i = 1) = 1/(n+1)$.

Comment: I see. How would you approach P(X=k) then?

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume $X$ counts only the monster cards picked, i.e. $X$ does not include the spell card itself.

Calculating $P(X=k)$ explicitly is not hard, because it just means the first card must be a monster, then the second must be a monster, ..., then the $k$th card must be a monster, then the $(k+1)$th card must be a spell.  Define $t = m+n$ for convenience.  We have:

$$P(X=k) = {m \over t} { m-1 \over t-1 } \cdots {m-(k-1) \over t-(k-1)} {n \over t-k}$$

---

Incidentally, if you want $E[X]$, the above is not the easy way to go. Instead, the professor's approach is excellent.  We have $E[X_i] = P(X_i = 1) = 1/(n+1)$ so by linearity we have $E[X] = m/(n+1)$, nice and simple.

Comment: X actually includes the spell card too. Also does it simplify into something nice? I tried simplifying it but got stuck: 

If X includes spell cards: $P(X=k) = (\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (m-i)/(m+n-i)) * n/(m+n-k+1) = \frac{m!(m+n-k-1)!}{(m-k-1)!(m+n)!} * \frac{n}{m+n-k+1}$. Not 100% on the last step but after that I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I didnt check your math but yeah you have the basic idea.  There is not much you can do after turning them into factorials.  Maybe you can convert them into some ${p \choose q}$ binomial coefficients, but IMHO that's not really _more_ simplified than factorials.

Comment: BTW I thought $X$ didn't include the spell card because you wrote $X = X_1 + \dots X_m$.  If it had included the spell card then obviously you need an additional $+1$ at the end.